# How can I stop deleted Google Analytics Cookies from returning?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

so I'm coding a cookie-component for a react-website. And I managed to set the cookies, and also to delete them. But I recognized that whenever I switch to another route, Google Analytics sets a Cookie again, even after I deleted them!

As you can see below, I try a few different things to delete everything, but it just shows up again!
Where does it come from? I wonder, if I can somehow discard that import maybe? Any tips?

```
import 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXXXX';

const cookieStorage = {
    getItem: (key) => {
      const cookies = document.cookie 
        .split(';')
        .map(cookie => cookie.split('='))
        .reduce((acc, [key, value, exdays]) => ({ ...acc, [key.trim()]: value }), {})
      return cookies[key];
    },
    setItem: (key, value) => {
      document.cookie = `${key}=${value};`;
    },
    deleteItem: (key) => {
      document.cookie = `${key}=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;`;
      document.cookie = `${key}=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;domain=.domain.de`;
      document.cookie = `${key}=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;domain=domain.de`;
      document.cookie = `${key}=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;domain=localhost`;
    },
    getItems: () => {
        const cookies = document.cookie 
          .split(';')
          .map(cookie => cookie.split('='))
          .reduce((acc, [key, value, exdays]) => ({ ...acc, [key.trim()]: value }), {})
        return cookies;
    }
  }

  const storageType = cookieStorage;
  
  const deleteCookies = () => {
    const allCookies = storageType.getItems();
    Object.entries(allCookies).forEach(cookie => {
        storageType.deleteItem(cookie[0]);
    })
  }
  
  window.onload = () => {

    /* Google Analytics */
      let gtm = window.google_tag_manager[process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS];
    /* ---------------- */

    const acceptFn = () => {
      /* Google Analytics */
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        
        function gtag(){
          window.dataLayer.push(arguments);
        }

        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS);
      /* ---------------- */

        saveToStorage(storageType);
    };

    const declineFn = () => {
        gtm.dataLayer.reset();
        window.google_tag_manager[process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS] = undefined;
        for(let i=0;window.dataLayer.length > 0;i++){
          window.dataLayer.pop();
        }
        
        deleteCookies(storageType);
    };


...
```

Comment: why are you deleting GA's cookies? You don't want GA to work properly?

Comment: @BNazaruk As a user, I need to be able to opt out of these cookies (if I maybe accidentally opted in) - at least in Germany

Comment: this is how it's done then: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/10718549?hl=en